# I cannot export woocommerce product description with html to csv

Tags: excel, wordpress, woocommerce, export-to-csv, excel-import

I am trying to export my woocommerce product description to csv with woocommerce functionality and not with plugin.

I then import my csv to excel file and product description is not included in one cell and in one column but it is spread to 2 or 3 columns

Why this is happening? Is something that I did wrong?

Comment: The problem is related to excel import parameters not to woocommerce that does his job correctly.

Comment: I opened notepad++ and I replace \r\n with \1 and I got a proper csv :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

I opened notepad++ and I replace \r\n with null and I got a proper csv